# Different answers for self-energy?

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy, coulombs-law, self-energy

If we calculate the self-energy using the energy density integral then we get
$$U=\int^\infty_0\frac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}dr=-\frac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 r}$$
However, since the potential of a point charge is given by $\phi=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}$ we can write
$$U=q\phi=+\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}$$
So why are these two answers differed by a factor of $-1/2$?

Answer (score 1):

Point charges are not great for using the integral formulation in order to find the total internal energy of the system. If you'll remember, the total energy of a system composed of $N$ point charges, when $V(\mathbf{r}_i)$ is the potential generated at the position of $q_i$ due to all the other $N-1$ charges is:
$$
U = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{N} q_i V(\mathbf{r}_i),
$$
where we clearly have not counted the influence of the $i$-th charge over itself. This formulation may be extended to a continuum, with charge density $\rho$:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \int \rho V\,\mathrm d\tau = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int E^2\,\mathrm d\tau,
$$

where $E$ is the electric field due to all the charges in the configuration. The integral is over all space. In this situation, $V$ is the **total potential**, whereas in the former, $V(\mathbf{r}_i)$ would not count the potential due to the $i$-th charge. For a continuous distribution there is no distinction, since the amount of charge right at the point $\mathbf{r}$ is so small.

Actually, if you'd calculate the internal energy of a point charge via an integral formulation, you'd get

$$
\frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int E^2\mathrm d\tau = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{q}{r^2} \right) r^2\sin\theta \,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\phi \rightarrow \infty,
$$

which is an embarrassment afflicting both quantum AND classical EM theory.

Comment: so u r saying that the real self-energy of a point charge according to classical em is given by $U=q\phi=+\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}$ and not the other one mentioned in the question?

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist

That'd be the work done to put some charge $q$ a distance $r$ away from another change $q$. The self-energy of a point particle is actually "**defined**" to be infinite in EM. Remember: the internal energy of a **system** is equal the least work done to construct that system.

Comment: A curiosity tho: for electrons, e.g., if you consider them actually an sphere of radius $R$ with homogeneous charge density (and electric charge $e$) and set the total energy of the system equals $mc^2$, where $m$ is the mass of the electron, you could solve for $R$ and it would give you the radius of a classical electron.